# Exit Node Jumping While Using StrictNodes in Torrc

Tags: configuration

I have seen a situation where I'm on non-onion website and the exit node jumps while the site is loading.  If I hit the "New Circuit for this Site" button, the exit node starts in RO and then jumps 2+ times to some non RO exit node before it finishes.  Have I got the code wrong (see below) in Torrc?

Thanks.

Code:

GeoIPExcludeUnknown 1

ExitNodes {RO}

StrictNodes 1

Edit:  It appears that the jumps in exit node occur AFTER the site is loaded.  This does not occur on all websites.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it said in [official docs](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes) - I'm citing:

> If StrictNodes is set to 1, Tor will treat solely the ExcludeNodes option as a requirement to follow for all the circuits you generate, even if doing so will break functionality for you (StrictNodes applies to neither ExcludeExitNodes nor to ExitNodes, nor to MiddleNodes).